# Create co-occurrence matrix from dictionary key, value(s) in Python

Tags: python, matrix, counter, defaultdict, find-occurrences

I am trying to create a co-occurrence matrix from a dictionary of unique keys with overlapping values (in Python 3). Here is my data structure:

```
keys = ['A','B','C','D']
vals = [[1,2],1,[1,3],2]

dict = {'A':[1,2], 'B':1, 'C':[1,3], 'D':2]}
```

How can I create matrix that counts the occurrences of the values for each key in the form:?

```
   1.  2.  3. 
A. 1   1   0 
B. 1   0   0 
C. 1   0   1 
D. 0   1   0
```

I've been recommended to use `defaultdict` but I am not sure how to implement it. 
Thank you!

Comment: what would the result be if it was `vals = [[1,2],1,[1,2],4]`? Note that there is no `3` in this case

Comment: 1.  2.  3.  4.
A. 1   1   0   0
B. 1   0   0   0 
C. 1   1.  0.  0.  
D. 0   0   0.  1

Comment: So the `3` would be included even if it is missing from the original data. Note that this is not covered by the otherwise great answer from [@Dani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60852143/6162307). This also highlights the need for a good general example!

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
d = {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1], 'C': [1, 3], 'D': [2]}

values = sorted(set(e for v in d.values() for e in v))

result = {k : [1 if value in v else 0 for value in values] for k, v in d.items()}

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'A': [1, 1, 0], 'B': [1, 0, 0], 'C': [1, 0, 1], 'D': [0, 1, 0]}
```

If there are many values you could use sets for the containment test, something like this:

```
d = {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [1], 'C': [1, 3], 'D': [2]}
d = { k : set(v) for k, v in d.items() }
```

A more concise way suggested by @Ev. Kounis is to do:

```
result = {k : [int(value in v) for value in values] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Finally if you are interested in a list of list data structure, (i.e a matrix), you could put the values of result in a list:

```
print(list(result.values()))
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: you could also do `[int(value in v) for value in values]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- there can be gaps in the values of the original dict which should not be skipped and
- you are only interested in the range defined by min and max value

you can do:

```
d = {'A':[1,2], 'B':[1], 'C':[1,3], 'D':[2]}

values_flat = {v for sub in d.values() for v in sub}
max_value = max(values_flat)
min_value = min(values_flat)

result = {k : [int(i in v) for i in range(min_value , max_value +1)] for k, v in d.items()}

print(result)  # {'A': [1, 1, 0], 'B': [1, 0, 0], 'C': [1, 0, 1], 'D': [0, 1, 0]}
```

*Note that I took the liberty to redefine and rename your original `dict`. Now all the values are lists. Consistent data are essential, so if you have any control over your input make sure you sanitize it first. Also note that `dict` is a bad variable name since it shadows the Python built-in.*